# Controlling screen settings (besides brightness)

Tags: android, settings, screen

Using Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL it is possible to set the screen brightness.

Is there any way to set other screen parameters, such as contrast and saturation, using the SDK? I'm trying to write an app that will change these parameters globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to set other screen parameters, such as contrast and saturation, using the SDK?

Those are not even controllable by users, let alone by developers. Sorry.